# Circular UIBarButtonItem button image get stretched

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

Added circular button on `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` for specific `UIViewController` of a `TabBarcontroller` after switching one tab and getting back to specific tab. The circular button is stretched.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    infoButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
    infoButton.sd_setBackgroundImage(with: URL(string: "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"), for: .normal)
    infoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    infoButton.layer.cornerRadius = infoButton.bounds.size.width / 2
    infoButton.clipsToBounds = true
    infoButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    infoButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    infoButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(hexString: "#AAC8FF").cgColor
    let infoItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: infoButton)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = infoItem
}
```

Error Image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to give `infoButton` a size. You have to use auto layout. Give it a width constraint with a constant 40 and a height constraint with a constant 40.

Comment: Thanks matt.... I really missed this constraint. :-(         NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
             infoButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
             infoButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
         ])